# What does Hindu scripture say about the need for clothing?

Tags: belief, culture, tradition, human, body

In most societies, clothing is a requirement to cover the private parts. But  Sadhguru Jaggi Vasudev in **[Future of Feminine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=65Q1EbsKRnY)** said that

> Our Body parts are **Not Secret** it is just that we learnt **How to handle our Body** and conduct it in a certain way.

So my question is, does Hindu scripture discuss the need for clothing?  And if so, what reason does it give?

Comment: 1. Jaggi makes all kinds of weird statements . Hindusim cannot validate them all 2. It is not only Hindu society that requires covering up. Indecent exposure is  crime even in non-Hindu countries.

Comment: @moonstar2001 i agree with you as it is SAID TO BE Indecent in the society for this kind of ones but there is NO REASON said why those two organs are specillay covered , IMO these two are PROTECTED(From Climate) and NOT HIDED

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58527/discussion-on-question-by-sakthi-what-does-hindu-scripture-say-about-the-need-fo).

Answer (score 5):

It says a lot of of things about the need for proper clothing.

For e.g. Manu Smriti 4.45

> नान्नमद्यादेकवासा न नग्नः स्नानमाचरेत् ।
>   न मूत्रं पथि कुर्वीत न भस्मनि न गोव्रजे ॥ ४५ ॥
>
> nānnamadyādekavāsā na nagnaḥ snānamācaret |
>   na mūtraṃ pathi kurvīta na bhasmani na govraje ||

He shall not eat food *with only one piece of cloth on him; he shall not bathe naked;* he shall not pass urine on the road, nor on ashes, nor on the haunts of cows.

This is just one example, I'm sure people can add more.

In Brahmin culture, there are separate types of clothing for married and unmarried men & women - so that, just by looking from long distance, we can find out if a person is married and give them respect or distance. Otherwise, it may lead to men talking to married women with an inappropriate mindset.

In ancient times, only boys used to attend school, so these rules were directed at men. It was then the duty of these men to instruct their wives when they married later in life. Whatever rules apply to men, most of them apply to women too.

Comment: +1 good answer but manu smriti must be telling the equal rights of men and women.
We males also knows and can have inappropriate mindset if a women is not dressed properly. Now please do not take it otherwise but it happens, off-course it is a fault of male of having inappropriate mindset, but it is also a duty of both males and females to cover their body as appropriate as possible. (That does not mean to always wear Indian dresses) 
But it is just that if maximum body parts are covered with a loose fit does not affect male much if you compare it to a exposing dress of a lady

Comment: @Rishi, yes I agree with you, both women & men have a role to play in decent clothing.. women moreso than men because that's the way natural desires are.

Comment: Right, the media and some reality serials completely forget our culture and are saying that it is only the male who is responsible for Rapes and eve teasing. Off-Course it is a fault of male. But in some cases of eve teasing women's dress makes a important point. What do you think about it ram? What i am trying to say is in at-least 40% cases of eve teasing girls dressing sense matters. Some people have experimented in new-york like cities and yes clothing matters a lot, a lot more in females.